# How to DELETE using multiple WHERE clauses [SQLITE]

Tags: sqlite

First question I would like to ask is, it is faster to make one delete query with multiple where clauses, or is it faster to do one by one?
And second if so then how to make delete query with multiple where clauses?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean something like `DELETE From STUDENTS Where Student_Id = 1 AND Student_Name LIKE '%An%'`?

Comment: @user2004685 he probably means with `OR` rather than `AND` since he proposes the alternative to do multiple queries instead.

Comment: Yes I would like to delete multiple rows at once like WHERE name=John surname=Doe and also WHERE name=Dog surname=Barf Something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have more than one `WHERE` clause, but you can make the condition more complex.

If your table has `FirstName` and `LastName`, and you want to delete `John Doe`, `Toby Steed`, and `Linda Powers`, then combine `AND` and `OR` conditions like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM MyTable
 WHERE ( FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Doe' )
    OR ( FirstName = 'Toby' AND LastName = 'Steed' )
    OR ( FirstName = 'Linda' AND LastName = 'Powers' )
```

Now, if you do it from Java, you shouldn't (EVER!) use string concatenation to build a SQL statement like that. Use a `PreparedStatement`:

```java
String sql = "DELETE FROM MyTable" +
             " WHERE ( FirstName = ? AND LastName = ? )" +
                " OR ( FirstName = ? AND LastName = ? )" +
                " OR ( FirstName = ? AND LastName = ? )";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "John");
    stmt.setString(2, "Doe");
    stmt.setString(3, "Toby");
    stmt.setString(4, "Steed");
    stmt.setString(5, "Linda");
    stmt.setString(6, "Powers");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And why shouldn't I use string concatenation to build a SQL statement? Like is it very bad if I do it like that?

Comment: @J.Arbet Because the values (e.g. `John`) are likely from an external untrusted source, and may be malicious or simply contain characters that cause SQL issues, e.g. an apostrophe. So, unless you make sure to escape all special characters, you become susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks (allowing hackers to steal and/or delete your data), or your SQL will simply fail, e.g. for `LastName = 'O'Malley'`. Using `setString()` is safe from those issues, and it also allow the database to better optimize the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this maybe is the solution of your question:

```
   db.delete(TABLE,
    KEY1 + "=? AND " + KEY2 + "=? AND " +
    KEY3 + "=? AND " + KEY4 + "=?",
    new String[] {param1, param2, param3, param4});
```

If you use a normal select use this:

```
   db.delete(TABLE,"Column1='value1' and column2 like 'value2'...", null);
```

Comment: Okay but I use the classic way like "SELECT * FROM table_name" or "DELTE FROM table_name WHERE name='John' AND surname='Doe'". Could you tell me how to make that thing right up there to be like this code?